# Parsing Array to Jquery Plug In

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [Responsive Calendar](http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/) Plug In which I need to dynamically create events.

How can I pass the arr event array as default event list to the plug in.

code is as follow.

[image]

Generated Event List is as follow

[image]

any support appreciated.

Actual Code should looks like this, that I need to create the event list from back end and pass it to the the event method.

```
$(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
    time: '2014-04',
    events: {
      "2014-04-30": {"number": 5, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com/responsive-slider"},
      "2014-04-26": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "http://w3widgets.com"}, 
      "2014-05-03": {"number": 1, "badgeClass": "badge-error"}, 
      "2014-06-12": {"class": "active cool"}}
  });
```

thx

Comment: Adding pictures of your code is not very helpful. Add the actual text instead.

Comment: @Tomanow : I have added the actual text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can u try like this ?

```
       <?php 
       $arrEvents = array();

       for($x = 1; $xdateOn = "2014-03-".$x;
       $objCalendar->number = $x;
       $objCalendar->badgeClass = "badge-warning";
       $objCalendar->url = "http://blog.iyngaran.info?id=".$x;
       array_push($arrEvents, $objCalendar);
       }

       ?>



    
       $( document ).ready( function() {
       $(".responsive-calendar").responsiveCalendar({
       time: '2014-03',
       events: {
          $event){?>
          "dateOn);?>": {"number": number);?>, "badgeClass": "badge-warning", "url": "url);?>"},
        
        }
        });
        });
```

Comment: It works and this way is easy, rather trying passing to function as java script array.